# iPhone 3G set time automatically?

Tags: iphone, clock

I've noticed on an old iPhone 3G I keep around for testing that the **Set Automatically** option in **Date & Time** doesn't work. This iPhone has a SIM card, but it has been deactivated by the carrier after upgrading to a newer model which uses a different size card.

I assumed it would work using [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), which means it should be able to sync the time over WiFi. But I haven't find any documentation on this.

I keep this iPhone around for testing, so it only comes out of the drawer every few months. Keeping it fully charged isn't a realistic option.

This phone is running the final version available for it, **iOS 4.2.1 (8C148)**.

My question, then: Can I make this work? Failing that, is there documentation available that says once and for all that it can't be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Set Automatically" takes the time from the cellular network. If you remove the SIM card (or just keep the phone in airplane mode with Wi-Fi enable), the time will never get updated.

From the [iPhone User Guide](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/book/iphone-user-guide-for-ios-5.1/id504972363?mt=11) (available in iTunes):

> If iPhone is set to update the time automatically, it gets the correct time over the cellular network and updates it for the time zone you’re in.
>
> Some carriers don’t support network time in all areas. If you’re traveling, iPhone may not be able to automatically set the local time.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. For posterity: I checked and I was wrong. I actually **do** have a SIM card, it just is an old one. Same problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can also turn off 3G Cellular and set manually.